# Debian 10 boot always starts in GRUB

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub

I have two physical drives with Windows installed on the one drive and Debian installed on the other one.

Every time I start Debian through the boot manager, the GRUB window appear. Every time I have to enter the following script in there:

```
set prefix=(hd1,gpt3)/boot/grub
set root=(hd1,gpt3)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
```

After that Debian can be started. I have even seen some commands in the web which should save these instructions and propagate them for the next boot, but they did not work for me.

Could you please explain me why GRUB starts every time and give me an advice about how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**:
I have tried

```
sudo update-grub
```

both after starting the system and if entering the recovery mode. The result is

[image]

However, this does not work. I do not see a new configuration, too. After starting Debian for the next time, the same GRUB window appears and I have to re-do the script above.

The `update` command, however, changed the order of boot configurations. Before that, I had

```
1. Windows Boot Manager
2. bla
3. Toshiba... (name of my second drive)
```

After executing `update` the order is

```
1. bla
2. Toshiba
3. Windows Boot Manager
```

"bla" and "Toshiba" both lead to GRUB. "Windows Boot Manager" starts Windows immediately. Is it also worth of mention that using both systems confuses the time. After Debian, Windows time is set an hour/two hours before the current time.

Comment: *I have even seen some commands...* Which ones and what was the result? All you should do typically is to run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I am sure that was the command I have seen several months ago. That does not work. I have updated the post.

Comment: If so you should check UEFI settings > Boot and confirm the correct entry is being booted. If, for example, you installed Debian twice or more then you may still have entries for old installations that (1) won't work unless redirected as you're doing and (2) are unaffected by any update.

Comment: Checking UEFI I see two relevant entries: "bla" and "Windows Boot Manager". "bla" starts GRUB, "Windows" - Windows. Placing "bla" before drives and the drives before "Windows" does not load Debian, but throws "You have to load the kernel first" error. Placing Windows after "bla" and before the drives allows me to enter my script and start Debian as usually. Placing "Windows" first just loads "Windows". So, nothing helps by switching the order of these two. I do not see any other configuration that was indeed created after the "update-grub" command. Nothing helps.